# What does this while loop do?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm looking at a "dumb" solution to the N queens problem and I am confused by a while loop that is in the code:

```
bool check(int b[8][8])
{

  for(int c = 7; c >= 0; c--)
  {
    int r = 0;
    while(b[r][c] != 1 ) //this is the while loop I was talking about
   {
    r++;
   } //end while loop

    for(int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
   {
    if(b[r][c-i] == 1)
        return false;
    else if ((r-i)>=0 && b[r-i][c-i] == 1)

        return false;
    else if ((r+i)<=7 && b[r+i][c-i] == 1)
        return false;
    }

  } 
return true;
}
```

In the int main() I have 8 for loops and in the innermost loop, I initialize the entire first row of the board to 1. Then I call the function, and after calling the function I reset the entire first row back to zeroes. I can display the int main if you guys need it.

Comment: For each column `c` controlled by the outer `for` loop, the `while` steps through the `r`th column of the array `b` looking a row where `b[r][c]` is not 1. It accesses memory out of bounds if every row has a 1 in the column. What more is there to say?  Is this a Knight's Tour or an Eight Queens problem, or a Checkers game?

Comment: Find who named these variables and slap them for me, hard.

Comment: Eight Queens. So since we are starting from the rightmost side of the board, this while loop basically skips from b[0][7] to b[1][7] since the program had already initialized the entire first row to be 1?

Comment: @Aesthete r=row c=column and b=board if it was unclear, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you indented your code.

The `while`-loop is within a `for`-loop. It is scanning the rows (`r`) in current column (`c`) until it finds a square (`b[r][c]`) where the value is not `1` (whatever that means, perhaps it means it is an empty square).

The fact that you cannot read this highlights the importance of sensibly-named identifiers and  of not using "magic numbers" in your code.

Recommend reading: [The Practice of Programming (Professional Computing) by Brian W. Kernighan and Rob Pike](http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos/ASIN/020161586X/johnsydotorg-21).

Answer (score 1):

The outer `for` is decrementing `c`. The value `c` is indexing an array element. The `While-loop` is iterating the head elements in the 2-dimensional array. As long as the array element at `[r][c]` is not equal to 1, you will continue checking. I don't see any bounds checking though on `r`.